# form field required not working

Tags: html, forms

I have a form and not sure why one field works for the required attribute and the other doest:

doesnt work

```
<input name="ch_register_first_name" id="ch_register_first_name" type="text" value="First Name" class="regular-text" required />
```

does work

```
<input type="checkbox" name="ch_register_agree" value="1" required>
```

Does it not work if there is a default value for a text box???? If so how do I keep the default value and make it required??

Comment: You can't. If something has a value, it isn't empty. What about using the `placeholder` parameter to display the initial 'label'?

Comment: Need to see if there's a `<form>` element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the [`placeholder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) attribute to display your 'label' inside of the `<input />` and remove the `value` attribute. This way, `required` is respected:

```
<input name="ch_register_first_name" id="ch_register_first_name" type="text" placeholder="First Name" class="regular-text" required />
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/emp0axy4/)

It's worth noting though, that you shouldn't really use `placeholder` in place of a true `<label>` element. For example, Mozilla (as always) puts it best:

> Do not use the placeholder attribute instead of a `<label>` element.
>   Their purposes are different: the `<label>` attribute describes the
>   role of the form element; that is, it indicates what kind of
>   information is expected, the `placeholder` attribute is a hint about
>   the format the content should take. There are cases in which the
>   `placeholder` attribute is never displayed to the user, so the form
>   must be understandable without it.

Comment: Man, I guess I havent done just simple forms in a while. I forgot about `placeholder`